# disable mouse event in other tab

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, devexpress

iam using xtra tab, and i got 3 tab. each tab got is the same button because i put it in a panel. what i want is how do i disable the button function or event when i switch to tab 3 but still can run the function when i switch to tab 1 and tab 2.

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
add_rec()
}

private void xtraTabControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
DevExpress.XtraTab.ViewInfo.XtraTabHitInfo hi = xtraTabControl1.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
   if (hi.HitTest == DevExpress.XtraTab.ViewInfo.XtraTabHitTest.PageHeader)
      {
      if (hi.Page.Name == "xtraTabPage1")
            {

            }
      
      if (hi.Page.Name == "xtraTabPage2")
            {

            }
      
     if (hi.Page.Name == "xtraTabPage3")
            {

            }
      }
}
```

what code should i put in here?

iam using devexpress

[image]

without using enable or visible property at the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the XtraTabControl's [SelectedPageChanging event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTabXtraTabControl_SelectedPageChangingtopic) in the following manner:

```
private void xtraTabControl1_SelectedPageChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTab.TabPageChangingEventArgs e)
{
    btnMyButton.Enabled = (e.Page == xtraTabPage1 || e.Page == xtraTabPage2);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage == tabPage1 ||    xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage == tabPage2)
   {   
     add_rec();
   }
}
```

Is that what you are looking for? This will check which TabPage is selected and just run the function if TabPage1 or 2 are Active.

Note that each TabPage is an own object, which is automatically created by designer if you create a XtraTabControl.

Comment: Or make set the panel or buttons `Enabled` property to suitable value in `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your tab control.